# Ruby Arrays with ljust / rjust / center

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have created the following code as part of an excercise in a Ruby tutorial I am trying:

```
title = ['Chapter 1: Numbers','Chapter 2: Letters','Chapter 3: Variables']
pages = ['Page 1','page 72','page 118']

linewidth = 40
header = '*Table of Contents*'

puts header.center linewidth
puts
puts ((title[0]).ljust linewidth/2) + ((pages[0]).rjust linewidth/2)
puts ((title[1]).ljust linewidth/2) + ((pages[1]).rjust linewidth/2)
puts ((title[2]).ljust linewidth/2) + ((pages[2]).rjust linewidth/2)
```

My question is can the above be done without clarifying which part of the array to display? i.e. can I just, in one bit of code, get it to list all titles and all pages in the array in order? If so how would this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output list like this:

```
titles.each_with_index do |title,index|
  puts title.ljust(linewidth/2) + (b[index] ? b[index].rjust(linewidth/2) : nil)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
>> title = ['Chapter 1: Numbers','Chapter 2: Letters','Chapter 3: Variables'] 
#=> ["Chapter 1: Numbers", "Chapter 2: Letters", "Chapter 3: Variables"]
>> pages = ['Page 1','page 72','page 118'] 
#=> ["Page 1", "page 72", "page 118"]
>> 
..   linewidth = 40 #=> 40
>> header = '*Table of Contents*' 
#=> "*Table of Contents*"
>> center = linewidth / 2 
#=> 20
>> puts header.center linewidth #=> nil
          *Table of Contents*           
>> puts 
#=> nil
>> title.zip(pages) do |t, p|
..     puts "#{t.ljust(center)} #{p.ljust(center)}"
..   end 
Chapter 1: Numbers   Page 1              
Chapter 2: Letters   page 72             
Chapter 3: Variables page 118 
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

`titles` and `pages` are *parallel arrays*.  `Array.zip` is great at handling parallel arrays:

```
title.zip(pages).each do |title, pages|
  puts (title.ljust linewidth / 2) + (pages.rjust linewidth / 2)
end
```

Comment: Ah nice thank you.  Parallel arrays and '.zip' isn't something that has been covered so far in my tutorial but looks like a much better solution.